# Cordova picking up wrong version of java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cordova

I am trying to run

```sh
cordova build android
```

It gives the following error

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/bappaditya/Softwares/android-studio (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/bappaditya/Softwares/android-studio (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

I can see that it has picked up `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` but not the correct version of java

### My current environment

```sh
>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)

>echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

>echo $PATH
/home/bappaditya/.cargo/bin:/opt/gradle/gradle-5.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/bappaditya/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

As you can see the JAVA 8 is installed and set as default. Why cordova complaining about java version?

Answer (score 1):

It seems cordova uses `javac` to identify the version and not `java`.

So the command that really shows the version cordova gets when looking for Java is:

```
javac -version
```

In my case, even though I had identical versions to what you have in your environment, it turned out my `javac` was pointing to a newly updated Java (from Ubuntu updates)

To fix it, I used the `update-alternatives` command and set `javac` back to my 1.8.0 version as follow:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```